# Confused about parameters by reference

Tags: c++, object, parameters, reference

Basically I have a function which returns a certain object. Let's say it returns an "Animal" object.

```
Animal Animal::breed(Animal &aFather)
  {
/*code*/
return Animal(<parameters>);
}
```

I have another function adding animals to a list. Here, the parameters are again passed as reference.

```
void Farm::addAnimal(Animal &newAnimal)
  {
  animals.push_back(newAnimal);
  }
```

Now, in main.cpp, if I do this:

```
Farm farm("This Is A Farm");
Animal * eva = new Animal(<parameters>);
Animal * adam = new Animal(<parameters>);
farm.addAnimal(*eva); //Works
farm.addAnimal(*adam); //Works

farm.addAnimal(eva->breed(*adam)); //Doesn't work.
//The function returns an Animal object yet it doesn't work.
//If I do this:

Animal animalBreed = eva->breed(*adam);
farm.addAnimal(animalBreed);
//It works.
```

Why??

If I do `farm.addAnimal(eva->breed(*adam));`
I get

```
     error: no matching function for call to 'Farm::addAnimal(Animal)'
   farm.addAnimal(eva->breed(*adam));
                                       ^
```

Comment: Short short answer: `addAnimal` accepts an lvalue reference, but you give it an rvalue. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c

Comment: Non-const references don't accept temporary values. It's probably a design error on your part to have `addAnimal` require a mutable reference.

Comment: Thank you! Adding "const" to my reference fixed it. Whoa.

Comment: Does this now mean that addAnimal accepts an rvalue  reference, since now a const reference accepts temporary values?